# Define a compiler symbol via shellscript in eclipse (stm32 workbench)

Tags: c, eclipse, shell, symbols, stm32

Since a longer time, I write software for an embedded system for a `stm32f4` processor.

Until now, I worked with my own toolchain with my own makefiles to build the binary. To have the advantage of an IDE, I decided to integrate the project into Eclipse (stm32 workbench: eclipse for the stm32 controller). To stop having an own toolchain, I now use the integrated AC6 toolchain.

Most of the things I have to do are working fine.

**My Problem**

In my own makefile, I have the following entries:

```
SVNREPREV := $(shell ./svnversion.sh ./inc/ ./Drivers/ ./libs/ ./linkerscripts/ ./makefsdata/ ./src/)
XCFLAGS += -DSVNREPOVERSION=\"$(SVNREPREV)\"
```

(The shell script returns a value like that -> 1234:1234M and it will be converted to a string)

I can use this value in my c code like this:

```
const char svnRepoRevision[] = SVNREPOVERSION;
```

**My Question**

How can I realize a similar behavior in Eclipse/stm32 workbench with the AC6 toolchain and created makefiles?

**My Tries**

Add the symbols under Project -> Properties -> C/C++ Build -> Settings -> Build Steps -> Symbols

```
SVNREPREV=$(shell ../svnversion.sh ../inc/ ../Drivers/ ../libs/ ../linkerscripts/ ../makefsdata/ ../src/)
SVNREPOVERSION="SVNREPREV"
```

the build ends with the following error:

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc: error: ../src/): No such file or directory
```

I tried different versions of set the "", but it had no effect, alway received an error.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: [This page](http://addisu.taddese.com/blog/inserting-svn-revision-number-in-your-cc-code/) has some hints for how to do this, through Eclipse's makefiles which seems a bit easier.

Comment: Nice link, thx :) I try the eclipse way with the makefile.defs. It seams to work fine. I will add a answer to my question asap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Manual**

Link to the used documentation: [here](http://addisu.taddese.com/blog/inserting-svn-revision-number-in-your-cc-code/)

Thanks to [unwind](https://stackoverflow.com/users/28169/unwind) for showing me this link

**Solution/Answer**

1. create empty makefile.defs file in project root folder

> Right-Click on projectroot folder -> New -> File

2. write needed command for svn revision in makefile.defs

`SVNREV:='"$(shell ../svnversion.sh ../inc/ ../src/)"'`

3. open c/c++ build settings, symbols

> Project -> Properties -> C/C++ Build -> Settings -> Build Steps -> MCU GCC Compiler -> Symbols

4. add symbol used in code

> Add value SVNREPOVERSION="$(SVNREV)" as Symbol

5. Save the project settings and build

The build is now working fine and I receive my svn revision number.
The makefile.defs is executed once. This will read the needed svnrevisions from the used folders. This value will be written into SVNREPOVERSION, which I use in my code.